# Image Steganography Using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, modulus, steganography

I have project about steganography using matlab. The project is to hide text into RGB image using a key. A key used to determine channel indicator of other channels. The code to input key is:

```
% input key
key = input('Please input key between 1 - 100 :\n');
if key < 1 || key > 100
   msgbox('invalid key');
end       

key = uint8(key);
```

Then to determine channel indicator, a key modulus 3, if key mod 3 = 1 then channel indicator is red, if key mod 3 = 2 then channel indicator is green, if key mod 3 = 0 then channel indicator is blue. I'm newbie in matlab, so please help me.
 Thanks..

Comment: Is the key supposed to be a simple choice, or is it a password that the decoder needs to know from which channel to extract?

Comment: yes, decoder must know the key to retrieve message.

Comment: This is a poor mechanism. 1 mod 3 = 4 mod = 1. Generally passwords are used to decrypt an extracted message since it had been encrypted before embedding, or to store your information in random pixels and not in a predictable order. In this case, the password would be the seed to the randomiser function.

Comment: key used to determine indicator, not to store data. Data will be stored in one of the two channels other than the indicator.

Comment: so the code is "doing what you say" - what's the question?